# Run two task asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm running a synchronous method. Inside it I have to run two big method, so I was thinking to run them asynchronously.. I was thinking something like

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    var doWorkTask_1 = DoWork1();
    var doWorkTask_2 = DoWork2();

    var result1 = await doWorkTask_1;
    var result2 = await doWorkTask_2;

    if(result1 == result2) 
       ....

    Thread.Sleep(syncInterval);
}
```

To do this i need that:

1. `DoWork1` and `DoWork2` are asynchronous;
2. `MyFunc` is asynchrous too;

But no method is asynchronous!!!

SO I tried to do in another way:

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    var doWorkTask_1 = Task.Run(() => DoWork1());
    var doWorkTask_2 = Task.Run(() => DoWork2());

    var result1 = doWorkTask_1.Result;
    var result2 = doWorkTask_2.Result;

    if(result1 == result2) 
       ....

    Thread.Sleep(syncInterval);
}
```

So, 1st question:
Do I have written same thing in two different ways?

2nd question. I have to run the `MyFunc` method every X time, so I call it in this way:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(MyFunc);
```

Can I call it simply

```
MyFunc();
```

My question is because inside `myFunc` I have a `Thread.Sleep`. Can I let sleep the main thread or is better to let sleep a thread inside the main?

I hope I have been clear. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you make `MyFunc` async? Or does it have to be synchronous?

Comment: I prefer to have it synchronous because if I do MyFunc async, I have to do also the method that call MyFunc async, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do `async` all the way, and by asynchronous you mean that you want to process `DoWork1` and `DoWork2` concurrently on different threads then you can use `Task.Run` to offload the work to a different thread and `Task.WaitAll` to wait **synchronously** for both tasks to complete:

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => DoWork1());
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => DoWork2());

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    if (task1.Result == task2.Result)
    {
        // ...
    }

    Thread.Sleep(syncInterval);
}
```

Now, since this uses 3 threads (two `ThreadPool` threads in `Task.Run` and the calling thread blocked on `Task.WaitAll`) when we only need 2 we can simplify and optimize the example by executing one of the operations on the calling thread:

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => DoWork1());
    var result2 = DoWork2();

    if (task1.Result == result2)
    {
        // ...
    }

    Thread.Sleep(syncInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Have I written same thing in two different ways?

No. Your first method will execute two units of work in *parallel*, and will **asynchronously wait** on the first one, then the second one.

Your second method will execute two units of work in *parallel*, and will **synchronously wait** on the first one, then on the second one.

> Can I let sleep the main thread or is better to let sleep a thread
>   inside the main?

That depends on what your application is doing. You could turn `MyFunc` to be `async` so you can use `Task.Delay` instead, which internally uses a *timer* and doesn't block (and you may also pass it a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) if needed):

```
public async Task MyFuncAsync()
{
   // Do work

   await Task.Delay(syncInterval);
}
```

**Side note:**

It seems to me like you may be using *async over sync*, [which in general is a questionable approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). I would advise against it.

Instead, like in your first example, explicitly invoke `Task.Run` on these workers:

```
public async Task MyFuncAsync()
{
    var firstTask = Task.Run(() => DoWork1());
    var secondTask = Task.Run(() => DoWork2());

    await Task.WhenAll(new[] { firstTask, secondTask });
    await Task.Delay(syncInterval);
}
```

Comment: Cannot I have an anonymous function inside Task.Run?

And How can I call MyFuncAsync ??? Simply MyFuncAsync(); Or Task.Factory.StartNew(MyFuncAsync) ??

Comment: @Ciccio I'm not sure what you mean. You *can* have an anonymous func inside `Task.Run`. How to call `MyFuncAsync`? `await MyFuncAsync();`

Comment: This is the problem I saying before... to call `await MyFuncAsync();`, I have to do async the method where I call My FuncAsync too.. And so on, with all the parent methods..

Comment: @Cicco You're right. That's why async is *all the way*, from the top to the bottom of your stack. Why is that a problem?

Comment: The first call is inside in a constructor... Can I do async my contructor?

Comment: @Ciccio No, you can't. But you can use the [*Initialize pattern*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: It's becoming too complex... Because, then I have to initialize the class with another `await` (`await myInstance.Initialization;`).. I'm going out of my scope... What If I simply call MyFunc `MyFunc` ?? It should run synchronously, but the two task inside run asynchronously, right?

Comment: @Ciccio You won't be able to `await` them. Don't use `async void`. Perhaps look at `TaskFactory.ContinueWith`.

Comment: What if I simply do `Task xxxx = MyFunc(); xxxx.Wait(); ` ??

Comment: @Ciccio Then you would be blocking. This may lead to a deadlock. I suggest you don't.

Comment: A deadlock? MyFunc is the only one task I wait for! I miss something... I believe I'll run everything synchronously

Answer (score 2):

Use `Task.WhenAll` to create a new task, encapsulating both your worker tasks.

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public async void MyFunc()
{
    var doWorkTask_1 = DoWork1();
    var doWorkTask_2 = DoWork2();

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(doWorkTask_1, doWorkTask_2);
}
```

Comment: but you need to make `MyFunc` async as well which apparently the OP doesn't want to do

Comment: @NedStoyanov The frequency at which i make that mistake has made the compiler start laughing at me..

Comment: You mean `var doWorkTask_1 = new Task( () => { DoWork1();});` ??

Comment: @Gusdor I often make the same mistake. SO should pop up a warning I think :)